# α-balanced focal loss - why we actually decrease the importance of positive class

Tags: neural-networks, binary-data, unbalanced-classes, computer-vision

[image: Focal loss]

This is the equation for Focal Loss. The loss is an extension of weighted cross entropy, and aims to balance the impact of majority of easy negative class samples. The α parameter is a weighing term which weighs the loss of class 1 by α, and class 0 by (1 - α). In the paper they give the value of α equal to 0.25.

My question is: why? Shouldn't it be something more like 0.75? To me it doesn't make intuitive sense that you would weigh down your loss for class 1 (underrepresented) relatively to class 0 (overrepresented). Could someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure you got the indices of the classes right? negative/positive, 0/1 can be confusing, they could be either in this formula.

Comment: Yes, this is consistent with the Focal Loss paper. 1 for foreground class, and that class is being weighted down more than the background class